# Laravel use query in creating event

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

what is best and clean way to insert a query value on creating event model like this (Laravel 5.7)

```
 public static function boot() {

    parent::boot();

    self::creating(function ($model) {


        $model->person_job = App\Job::where('person_name',$request->name);

    });

}
```

i don't wanna put this routine query in my controller , so what do professional developers here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `request()` function(helper) anywhere in your project if you have no `$request` variable.

In `MVC` architecture logic must locate in `Controller` mostly, Here in Laravel, events mostly are used to do some specific logic(I think that logic mostly does not rely on a user's given data as you do here) on every model based on the event, for example, if you want to generate a `unique_id` for each `Model` on `created || creating` event, or doing `caching` or something like that.

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#introduction) for more about events.

Comment: Looking good , but what about using query inside eloquent event ? is that good to put it in static or non-static method?  can you explain more , i wanna know the best way here that other developers do

Comment: hmm, so i should move it to controller section? but i think it not really clean

Comment: Yes, I think there is no need to do that logic there in the events.